# Populate Random records with apriory known distribution in DB2 / SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, db2

To make it simple, here is the story: I have to create test data of, say, country names.
I have a simple table like this one:

```
create table countries(name varchar(16), percentage float);
```

populating it with 3 countries

```
insert into countries values
('USA',0.5),
('England',0.3),
('Germany',0.2);
```

Note that percentage sums up to 100%.

Now, I want this table to be used for creation of the REAL data table of, say, 1000 records
which has a single column (name), and the values are distributed as the countries table defines (USA 50% - 500 records, England 30% - 300 records and Germany 20% - 200 records).

I know it can be done with a case statment, but I prefer to get a solution where the SQL is stable and I can change just the countries table (e.g. adding countries, etc.)

My environment is DB2 9.5

Comment: In SQL you can multiply numbers with the `*` operator.

Comment: You are aware that certain fractions can't be represented precisely, correct (ie, 1/3)?  Also, that floats/doubles can't precisely encode some values (ie .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 != 1)?  And why do you want multiple copies of the same value?  Denormalization like that is terrible (there are places for it, but not what I've heard so far).

Comment: This is just part of the story. Once I have these multiple records I'll update the rows having the same "name" and will also shuffle the rows using the rand() function. Yes. I understand the fraction precision. This is not a problem at all. Just wanted to know if SQL is able to do it WITHOUT stored procedure code.

Comment: Update the same name rows _how_?  If you change the name they're initially created with, why didn't you create them with that name in the first place?  As for randomizing them... you _do_ realize SQL has **ABSOLUTELY NO** sense of order (barring the use of the specific clause), right?  In other words, it doesn't matter what the actual order in the table is!  'Randomizing' a single-column table is not only pointless, it's pretty much impossible.  Why do you need some 'random' order?  Often a deterministic order suffices...

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking on small numbers such as 1000 rows, it will be faster if you prepare and check numbers in a spreadsheet.  On the other hand, storing a column of data that has to add 1 has several problems:  How are you going to manage the update on one row in order to keep the sum of the column equal to 1?  It's a better idea to store the original numbers (let's say, population, gross domestic product, etc.) and calculate the percentage at the reporting or consulting time, so when a number changes for a particular country you won't have to make complex adjustments and the application will still be able to show them accordingly.